# Can this Javascript redirect be exploited in some way?

Tags: xss, javascript, url-redirection

Since I can modify pathname, search and hash value could I leverages this in some way?

```
var URL = window.location.hostname+window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;
 
var sURL = "https://" + URL ;
 
window.location = sURL ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're imagining you might do, but the answer is no. String concatenation isn't inherently unsafe, nor is the code doing anything unsafe with the concatenated string. Redirecting to an HTTPS URL is the opposite of unsafe, and assuming you control the initial URL you could direct the "victim" to any URL you wanted anyhow.

If it was possible to change the URI scheme to something potentially unsafe (like `javascript:` or `data:`) you might have an attack vector for XSS. Even then, though, it'd be tricky to get something close enough to correct to load the page at all but also containing a meaningful payload, even if swapping out the expected scheme was somehow trivial. In any case, the scheme is hardcoded here, and you're not going to be able to change it.

Comment: I couldn't find anyway to exploit it but I wasn't sure I could consider it safe :).